# Why can't I use NextJS's useRouter in a child of a component that uses getServerSideProps or getInitialProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, algolia

I have a NextJs page that uses getInitialProps to fetch search results from algolia like so:

```
function MarketplacePage(props) {
  const { router, page, seoProps, ...restProps } = props;
  const setStateId = useRef();
  const [searchState, setSearchState] = useState(
    pathToSearchState(router.asPath)
  );

  const onSearchStateChange = (nextSearchState) => {
    clearTimeout(setStateId);

    setStateId.current = setTimeout(() => {
      const href = searchStateToURL(router, nextSearchState);

      router.push(href, href, {
        shallow: true,
      });

      setSearchState(nextSearchState);
    }, debounceTime);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Marketplace</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/cu_icon.svg" />
      </Head>

      <SearchApp
        {...defaultProps}
        searchState={searchState}
        resultsState={restProps.resultsState}
        onSearchStateChange={onSearchStateChange}
        createURL={createURL}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

MarketplacePage.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const { req, res, query, ...restProps } = context;

  const searchState = pathToSearchState(restProps.asPath);
  const resultsState = await findResultsState(SearchApp, {
    ...defaultProps,
    searchState,
  });

  return {
    resultsState,
    searchState,
  };
};

const MarketplaceWithRouter = withRouter(MarketplacePage);

export default MarketplaceWithRouter;
```

Which sends props to a child, SearchApp:

```
function SearchApp({ indexName, searchClient, searchState, ...restProps }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <InstantSearch
        indexName={indexName}
        searchClient={searchClient}
        searchState={searchState}
        resultsState={restProps.resultsState}
        onSearchParameters={restProps.onSearchParameters}
        onSearchStateChange={restProps.onSearchStateChange}
        createURL={restProps.createURL}
        {...restProps}
      >
        <TopNav />
        <div style={{ marginTop: 80 }} />
        <div style={{ width: 700, marginLeft: 50 }}>
          <CustomSearch searchAsYouType={false} />
        </div>
...
```

SearchApp then calls my navbar, TopNav, which looks like:

```
function Navbar(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState(null);

  const logo = "/images/image.svg";

  const pathname = router.pathname;

...
```

This gives the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of null.

The call stack shows: getInitialProps
pages\marketplace\index.js (73:46)

If I remove all references to pathname, I get error cannot read property 'user' of null on the auth hook which ultimately relies on useContext.

I also had two useContext hooks which resulted in similiar errors.

I get the same problem with getServerSideProps as well.

Can anyone tell me why?

Any help is appreciated.